# Change time after which locked computer turns off display

Tags: windows-10, external-display, display-settings

I have (I think) a standard sleep / turn off display settings in my Windows 10:

[image]

Yet my computer turns off display after 30 seconds since locking the computer.

If I lock computer manually, display's power is cut-off (display is turned off) after just 30 seconds since lock / stop of work. If I stop the work, but do not lock the computer then Windows locks it up after two minutes and then turns off the display after another 30 seconds.

*To summarize*: My display is never turned of after 15 minutes, despite above settings, it lasts turned on for between 30 seconds and 150 seconds at most.

How can I control when my display *for locked computer* is turned off, or how can I enforce that my display will always be turned of -- as set / said -- after 15 minutes and not even a second earlier?

**Edit**: *I went through all advanced power settings etc., all for nothing -- everything I look or check, I can clearly see the same setting -- 15 minutes. I must be looking in an incorrect place, though.*

Comment: If you've exhausted your `Advanced Power Settings`, try going to `Personalize`, then `Lock screen`, and checking your `Screen saver settings`. There's a chance your computer is hitting that default one minute wait time on a blank screen saver. Check the box for `On resume, display logon screen` and change your wait time to the 15 minutes you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Registry Editor, either by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `regedit` in the Run dialog and hit enter, or simply typing "regedit" in Windows Start.

1. In the Registry go to the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7
   ```

   and set the **`Attributes`** **DWORD** value from **1** to **2**

   [image: Screenshot of Window titled Registry Editor]
2. Goto **Power Options** > **Change plan settings** > **Change advanced power settings**

   [image: Screenshot of Window titled Power Options]

   [image: Screenshot of Window titled Edit Plan Settings]
3. In the Power Options dialog now you can see a new setting under **Display** > **Console lock display off timeout**

   [image: Screenshot of Window Dialog titled Power Options]

   Change the default time of 1 minute to the time you want, in minutes.

At any time, you can revert the changes by switching the registry value key (shown above) from **2** back to **1**.

Source: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-extend-lock-screen-timeout-display-turn-windows-10